# ISP router interface missing a lot of settings

Tags: router, internet, isp, pppoe

I'm thinkng of upgrading my garbage ONT modem/router that was provided to me by my ISP (Orange Morocco). The major problem is in their Router (ZTE F660) they're running a custom firmware in which they disabled so many things such as the entire WAN menu, so I can't even create a new connection with bridge mode for example. I contacted them asking for the PPPoE credentials and they said that they chose not to disclose this information due to some security reasons. So now I can't use my modem as a bridge and connect it to a powerful router, and I can't even get another modem and set it up since I don't have the PPPoE credentials and I don't want to use my new router as a mere access point. Do I have any other solution? Thank you.

Comment: Standard practice with many ISPs. They only support what they provide so no bringing your own superior device in. And yes, crippled firmware. There are security reasons, but also practical ones - if they allowed average home users to fumble with the Internet connection settings, they'd be drowning in technical support calls. Pretty much same applies to upgrading to your own device. I see really only two conceivable options - change to a business account, those sometimes allow upgrading hardware; or take the new router back to the shop and discuss with the ISP about other upgrade options.

Comment: Changing to a business account is unfortunatelly not possible since they cost so much more, and my ISP won't allow the use of another router so I guess I'm out of luck.

Comment: That was my experience when I tried to do the same. Luckily I called before investing in a router.

Comment: The problem is they literally only have two routers for their optical fiber plans and they'are both ZTE and they are garbage :(

Comment: Gotta keep in mind that vast majority of the target audience has computer literacy on the level of "There's no Start button, just the normal keyboard" :-P What they offer is good enough for them. I don't know what your specific need is, but I've tried all kinds of things starting with reverse SSH tunnels just to get around some of the ISP limitations. And gave up.

Comment: Personally I hope there was a middle tier. Add between "home user" and "business user" a "nerd user" level that'd at least allow things like upgrading a effin router.

Comment: Yess that would be so much better than just having these two. I think I'll just check with the local repair shops in see if they have a way of bypassing all of this

Comment: Good luck mate :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience this is usually a no-go. Exactly the same routers are commercially available, but many of the options in their firmwares are stripped off from ISP routers - and there's usually no way even to upgrade the FW. Replacing them with other, even technically superior devices is also not possible.

One reason is simply practicality. A hopeful user reads from the internet that setting PPPoE MTU to 1536 improves the performance => a call to technical support. There are many hopeful users following internet advice.

Allowing replacement with other devices carries similar load. Support personnel would need to have at least cursory knowledge of a very large number of devices. Also allowing devices the ISP has no control over opens the doors to severe security risks.

This naturally does not apply to all ISPs everywhere, and there might be ways to bypass limitations. I just want to make a point that before trying to replace ISP:s hardware in a home environment it's a good idea to call them and ask whether they allow it, and if yes, can they provide a list of supported / recommended devices etc.